Who do I reach when calling 116117 abroad and how do I ensure reaching the local version?
I was travelling in Norway with my German phone.  When I phoned 116117 due to a non-emergency medical problem¹, I received an answering machine speaking German.  Assuming I was connected to the German 116117 and not the Norwegian one, I hung up, as I concluded this was not useful to me.
Was my conclusion correct?
When I phoned 116117 in Norway, did I reach the German 116117, or was the Norwegian 116117 speaking German to me?  The number is already deployed in both countries.
Even if I was connected to the German one, could they have helped me still?
If they could not, how can I make sure I connect to the Norwegian 116117 when in Norway?  I tried +47116117, but this number was not recognised.

¹116117 is the harmonised European phone number reserved for non-emergency (or at least non-life threatening) medical problems, implemented in Germany, Norway, and some other countries.

Interesting.  I was unaware of these 116 numbers but I see that some are in operation here in the UK.  116117 does not seem to be operational yet.  The service you describe sounds like our 111 service.  This is medical advise and, provided that you were able to talk to them, I would not expect that it would matter where they were.  If they think that the issue is serious, they will recommend 999 or 112 for an ambulance; of course, that will need to be local.  It would be impressive, if it detected that your phone was German and it connected you to a German speaking operator.

As far as I understand it, while on 2G/3G phone numbers were interpreted by the visited network, on 4G/5G it’s the home network which handles it. There are exceptions for emergency calls (112), but the rest depends on the roaming agreements. So it’s indeed likely you were routed to the German 116117, but it’s difficult to say for certain. As a side note, 116117 is not yet deployed everywhere.

It does not seem to be deployed in the UK yet but 111 sounds like the same service.

@badjohn At least in Germany, they can book an appointment in a nearby out-of-hours doctor's office (or at least warn them that you're coming) for issues urgent enough that they shouldn't wait for Monday morning, but not urgent enough to go to Accidents & Emergency or call an ambulance.  I don't know what they recommend travellers.  I believe in Sweden such a phone appointment is even mandatory for out-of-hours doctors services.  No clue about Norway, but they might do more than only medical advice.

@badjohn The Wikipedia page on the topic says it's assigned to the NHS 111 in the UK. On the other hand, it says it's not assigned in France when it apparently is (haven't tried it, but Google returns tons of press releases and other pages on the topic, saying that in many places it goes to the doctor on call in the area, not sure it's the same everywhere).

@jcaron Ah — by learning it works in Germany and Norway I somehow extrapolated that it's probably an EU/EEA-wide thing, but apparently not quite yet!

What's agreed at the EU level is to reserve the number, implementation always takes years, even what actually happens when you call 112 still varies widely.

@gerrit The number has been set aside EU/EEA-wide for that purpose, but there's apparently no obligation (yet?) for countries to implement it, and implementation varies. Note that not even everyone agrees on what the number does. The EU says "non-emergency medical assistance" while France says "emergency but not life-threatening medical assistance" for instance.

@jcaron I guess that I hit upon an out of date source.  I don't want to test it as I don't want to waste any of their time.

Did you listen to enough of the recorded message to gather what it was saying? Or did you hang up as soon as you realised it wasn't Norwegian?

@TripeHound I hung up as soon as I realised it wasn't Norwegian.  To my defence, I wasn't feeling very well so maybe not acting optimally…

Just a guess, but since you said it was a machine, it might be that the answering language was based on the phone, rather that on the operator. This makes sense, since the number it's meant to be used by foreigners as well as residents.

There are unfortunately too many unknowns to be able to answer your question definitely. It may depend on the network you are roaming on, it may depend on your home network and it may even depend on the settings on your own telephone. The phone app on my telephone has its own setting wether to consider numbers dialled without a country code while roaming to be in the roaming country or in your home country and this will override however the operators interpret the number.
I can't replicate your situation exactly, but only try the other way around (with German and Norwegian subscriptions while in Germany) and my results are:

Dialling 116117 or +49116117 from a German cell phone will connect me to the German service.
Dialling +47116117 from a German cell phone will give me a 'there is no connection for the number you have dialled' message from the German network.
Dialling 116117, +49116117 or +47116117 from a Norwegian phone will ring once, then disconnect. The mentioned setting in my phone app does not have any impact on the behaviour. This is odd. I would expect to reach the German service when dialling 116117, or at least if I dialled +49116117.

There are some relevant differences in how the service is implemented on a national level in both countries, which may explain what I am seeing:

In Germany, dialling 116117 will initially connect you to a nation wide service, which will give you an automated message about what the service provides and then ask you to dial your postal code, after which you are connected to a local operator in charge of the area you have requested. The service can in principle be dialled from abroad under the number +49116117, but you will still need to enter a German postal code and will be connected to a local service.

In Norway, dialling 116117 will automatically connect you to the closest emergency ward using positioning data from your phone operator. The number is not reachable from abroad. If you need to call an emergency ward from abroad or somewhere else in Norway, you need to find their regular phone number and call that instead.


Looking into the publicly available technical details on the 116117 service in Norway, the service is operated by Telenor and they use designated interfaces to the Norwegian mobile phone operators to obtain location data for the callers. This means, that it might not be possible to provide reliable location data for you if you are roaming with a foreign subscription, but in that case, at least the rather old documentation I could find states that you should be connected to an 'alternative service', either to a manual operator able to forward your call to the correct area or a system similar to the one implemented in Germany, where you are asked to dial your postal code.
None of this will unfortunately allow a reliable answer to your question. Without knowing what the message you heard was saying, at least these two options are possible:

You were connected to the Norwegian 116117 service, which could not locate you but recognized that you were calling from a German number and therefore gave you a message in German, telling that they need some kind of assistance from you to find your location.

Especially if your phone is configured to treat numbers dialled when roaming as if they were in your home country, it is also likely that you reached the German service, which always answers with an automated message asking you to provide your location.



Routing may also depend on whether one is using 2G/3G (wherever that still exists) or 4G/5G, and whether the phone recognises the number as an emergency number or not. Also note that short numbers do not necessarily work with an international prefix.

@jcaron Tha may be, but there is no obvious difference in the result if I dial 116117, +49116117 or +47116117 with a Norwegian SIM in Germany wether I am on a 2G, 4G or 5G network. There is no 3G network available here to try on.
